# got this error "image "pyimage2" doesn't exist" while generating a tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am generating a tkinter window that contains an image but getting this error.

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = Tk()
win.geometry("1900x2000")

img = cv2.imread('lambo.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

im = Image.fromarray(img)

imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)

Label(win, image= imgtk).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

please help me!!

I don't know where should make the correction.

Comment: I do not get that error when I run this code.

Comment: Is this script imported by other script? Is another instance of `Tk()` created elsewhere in that other script?

Comment: Please provide more details about the error, including the traceback.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue using posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your image file is in the same directory.

Otherwise, try the following code :

```
lamboImg= tkinter.PhotoImage(file="lambo.jpg")
lamboImgLabel = tkinter.Label(win,image=lamboImg)
lamboImgLabel .place(x=90, y=77)
```

Don't forget to import :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Replace coordinates to place the image on the window.

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Note that `tkinter.PhotoImage()` does not support JPEG image.

Comment: @acw1668 i've always used it ! never had a problem... And if it don't works with jpeg just convert it to png